# string tokenization in C++ including delimiter characters

Tags: c++, stl

I have strings of following form
`a = x + y` or `abc = xyz + 5` or `6 + 5` or `f(p)`

What i need is to tokenize the string such that I read each `operator` and `operand`
so for `a = x + y` tokens returns should be `a,=,x,+,y` and in case of `abc=xyz+5` it should return `abc,=,xyz,+,5`. please note that there may or may not be spaces between `operator` and `operands`

this is what I have tried

```
void tokenize(std::vector<std::string>& tokens, const char* input, const char* delimiters) {
    const char* s = input;
    const char* e = s;
    while (*e != 0) {
        e = s;
        while (*e != 0 && strchr(delimiters, *e) == 0) {
            ++e;
        }
        if ( *e != ' ' && strchr(delimiters, *e) != 0 ){
            std::string op = "";
            op += *e;
            tokens.push_back(op);
        }
        if (e - s > 0) {
            tokens.push_back(std::string(s,e - s));
        }
        s = e + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like homework

Comment: If it isn't homework, I'd like to see a [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) answer. I've never quite understood how to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this implementation.
First argument is the std::string you want to tokenize, second argument is the delimiter you want to use. It returns a vector of strings tokenized. Very simple yet efficient.

```
vector<string> tokenizeString(const string& str, const string& delimiters)
{  
   vector<string> tokens;
   // Skip delimiters at beginning.
   string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
   // Find first "non-delimiter".
   string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

   while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
    {  // Found a token, add it to the vector.
      tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
      // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
      lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
      // Find next "non-delimiter"
      pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
   }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: This one will remove the delimiters , it will not push delimiters found in the string

Answer (score 4):

This example uses a [boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int , char* [])
{
    const string formula = " ABC + BYZ =6 +5";

    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ", "+-=");

    tokenizer tokens(formula, sep);

    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
        std::cout << "<" << *tok_iter << "> ";
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

<ABC> <+> <BYZ> <=> <6> <+> <5>

Spaces are skipped, delimiters are included

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for non-boost solution