# Dynamically construct a char in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I am trying to construct an array that has a series of character that I want to construct in the fly, the characters are like this `\x01`,  `\x02` and so on.

For example, lets say we have:

```
#define NUMCOLORS 3
char delim[NUMCOLORS];
```

And we want to have in `delim` the values `\x01, \x02, \x03`.

I thought two possible ways to do it, but both cause a segfault:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMCOLORS; i++){
  char *h = "\x01";
  sprintf(h, "\x0%d", i+1);
  strcpy(delim[i], h);
}

// Other way

for (int i = 0; i < NUMCOLORS; i++){ 
  char *h = "\x0";
  strcpy(delim[i], h+1);
}
```

Is there a way I can create the `char` I need

Comment: You can't `sprintf` into `h` because it's pointing to a read-only memory section. You cannot `strcpy` into `delim[i]` because it is a `char`, not a `char` pointer!!!

Comment: Do you know about [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't use `strcpy` as it will add the string terminator. Also, doing `h + 1` give you the next character in the string pointed to by `h` which is the string terminator.

Instead use the fact that a character is actually an integer value. That means you can do e.g.

```
char delim[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    delim[i] = i + 1;

/* Terminates as string */
delim[3] = '\0';
```

Now you can use `delim` as any other string in C, and contain the string `"\01\02\03"`.

---

If you want the string to contain not the *characters* `'\01'`, `'\02'` etc, then you need a bigger array, and another way of constructing the string:

```
/* 3 sequences of 4 characters (backslash, x, two digits), plus terminator */
char delims[3 * 4 + 1] = { 0 };  /* Initialize to zero (the string terminator) */

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    char temp[5];  /* Place for 4 characters plus terminator */
    sprintf(temp, "\\x%02d", i);

    strcat(delims, temp);
}
```

Now after this the *string* `delims` will contain the string `"\x01\x02\x03"`. Note that the backslashes are real backslashes, not something that the compiler will translate, if you print the string to the console the output will be exactly that, backslashes an all.

Comment: But that just fill delim with 1,2,3, I needed to be "\x01" "\x02" and "\x03"

Comment: @algui91 Do you want an array of *characters* or of *strings*?

Comment: @algui91 Also, the integer value `1` is equal to the *character* literal `'\01'`.

Comment: Let see, I have a string that I need to parse eg. "Hello, \x01 wolrd\x02", \x01 and \x02 represent colors, then I need delim to be "\x01\x02" in order to parse it with strtok.

Comment: @algui91 If you want to use it as a string, see my updated answer.

Comment: The first approach works like a charm, What do you think is better?

Comment: @algui91 If the first one works, the second will not work. And vice verse too of course. The two variants constructs different strings, I included them both because I was unsure of what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *h = "\x01"; ( will place \x01 in the read-only parts of the memory )
sprintf(h, "\x0%d", i+1); // not valid
```

this is pointer pointed to constant string. it's illegal to modify it. Read this my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703720/i-feel-confusion-about-bus-error-in-string-c/22703925#22703925)

Answer (score 0):

The notation `"\x01"` is a way to tell the *compiler* "When you create the constant to represent this string literal, replace me with the character with the numeric value `1`."  *The backslash (and `x`) does not even make it into the compiled module.*  If you want a character of a certain (dynamic) numeric value in a string, simply append that numeric value (cast to `char`) to the string.  Joachim gives you some ideas.

The `"\x01"` notation is just a "convenience" when you have some fixed numeric value you wish to insert into a string literal.