# Extracting multiple sub-strings from a string

Tags: c++, string, sockets

Below is an example of a message sent from a Client and received by the Server.

```
"P_ID:[1]MSG:[This is a test message...]"
```

How can I extract the information between `P_ID:[]` & `MSG:[]` on the Server effectively and remove the brackets from the information?

For example:

Turning `MSG:[This is a test message...]`

into `This is a test message...`

Comment: Use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823263/string-tokenization-in-c-including-delimiter-characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and most obvious way would be [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)("MSG:[") and then  [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) () to get the rest.

Something like that:

```
size_t start = data.find("MSG:[");
std::string msg = data.substr(start, data.find("]", start) - start);
```

But a more elegant and flexible way in c++11 would be using regex via std::regex_match on the regex `MSG:\[(.*)\]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var subString = data.SubString(data.IndexOf('['),data.IndexOf(']'));
```